# Why does adding imageview to navigation bar in storyboard remove navbar?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a working app which is a tabbarcontroller based app.  The first viewcontroller is a uitableviewcontroller.  All 3 tabs have a navigation bar on the top, that I added from the object library.  This is what the app looks like:

[image: Original UITableViewController in first tab with UINavbar]

Then I wanted to set the image on the navbar as a centered logo.  So I looked around SO and found code that looks like this:

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon57.png"];
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
 self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

or

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon57.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But it didnt work.  I just got an empty white nav bar.  So I decided to add a UIImageView to the navbar by dragging it in from the object library but for some reason it makes the navbar disappear and I end up with this:

[image: After adding UIImageView to UINavBar]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The way you are doing it is not supported in Interface Builder.  I would encourage you to [file a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) to support doing that.  You can accomplish this via two different ways, one in code, the other in IB.

**Through Interface Builder**

You can drag a `UIView` instance from the object library and drop it into the center of the nav bar.  This will set the view inside the title area of the bar.  You may then take a `UIImageView` instance and add it as a subview of that the view you just added.

**Through Code**

You can set the `UIImageView` through code, using the `titleView` property of your view controller's navigation item:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logo];
}
```

EDIT:

In order to set it on the left side, you'll have to wrap the image view in a `UIBarButtonItem`.  You can do that in IB using the same procedure described above, or in code like the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logo];    
    UIBarButtonItem *imageButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = imageButton;
}
```

Comment: Ok, just one last thing.  How do I make it be on the left side of the bar and not in the center?

Comment: One last doubt, since I dropped a UINavigationbar onto my UIViewController, which is inside a uitabbarcontroller, in order to have that code work, I need to get the navigation bar reference in code first, right?

Comment: @marciokoko  You shouldn't be adding the navigation bar directly to your view controller.  Your view controller should be embedded in a `UINavigationController`, which in turn is embedded in a `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Well I dont need the functionality of the bar, just the look...to display a title in a nice looking bar :) Should I embed it anyway and just not use the functionality?